# Displays two urls one link and desciption how to solve

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

My column in the list has this values

Links  Type the Web address: (Click here to test)

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Links" DataTextField="Links" 
                HeaderText="Date" />
```

Type the description: 
  the code in bottom is the code for my link it shows duplicates of the url because its link and desciption but i only want the link...

[image]

Comment: @Fox do u maybe now how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you could use a PlaceHolder manipulate your data and print the result do you want

Answer (score 0):

What I do is on code behind getting SPFieldUrl object and after I get the right value put it in the Literal control on Aspx side.

See [this](http://sreedharchavali.blogspot.be/2010/02/reading-writing-spfieldurl-field-values.html?m=1) article!

Maybe it will help,

Andrew